# Estou com uma dúvida idiota, porém faz um tempo já e não sei resolver isso. (MySQL)

Tags: banco-de-dados, mysql, back-end, dbeaver

Estava tentando criar uma tabela no mySql, simples, porém estava dando um erro. Resolvi baixar uma ide (DBeaver), continuou dando erro, então baixei o MySql WorkBench e ele não gera a tabela. Vejam o erro:

```
CREATE TABLE `wmp_fut`.`contratos` (
  `id_campeonato` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome_campeonato` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `negociacoes` ENUM('Aberto', 'Fechado') NOT NULL,
  `validade` DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT 2020-01-01,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_campeonato`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `nome_campeonato_UNIQUE` (`nome_campeonato` ASC));
```

```
Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
Executing:
CREATE TABLE `wmp_fut`.`contratos` (
  `id_campeonato` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome_campeonato` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `negociacoes` ENUM('Aberto', 'Fechado') NOT NULL,
  `validade` DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT 2020-01-01,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_campeonato`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `nome_campeonato_UNIQUE` (`nome_campeonato` ASC));

ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-01-01,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_campeonato`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `nome_campeonato_UNIQUE`' at line 5
SQL Statement:
CREATE TABLE `wmp_fut`.`contratos` (
  `id_campeonato` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome_campeonato` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `negociacoes` ENUM('Aberto', 'Fechado') NOT NULL,
  `validade` DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT 2020-01-01,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_campeonato`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `nome_campeonato_UNIQUE` (`nome_campeonato` ASC))
```

. Alguém sabe resolver? MySql e BDs em geral não são a minha linguagem, desculpem a pergunta idiota.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-01-01

A mensagem informa que o problema está na sintaxe e o local é próximo onde se encontra escrito "-01-01". No seu exemplo esse local é o campo `validade`. No caso foi passado um tipo de dado que não é esperado pelo campo.

Utilize aspas para setar valores do tipo `DATE`. Isso deve resolver seu problema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `wmp_fut`.`contratos` (
  `id_campeonato` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome_campeonato` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `negociacoes` ENUM('Aberto', 'Fechado') NOT NULL,
  `validade` DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT '2020-01-01',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_campeonato`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `nome_campeonato_UNIQUE` (`nome_campeonato` ASC)
);
```

Comment: Amigo, obrigado!